# How do I get a list an array of items with its associated values in another table in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I have a table [image]

I want to get the values categories like this from the next table
[image]

All I want to get from the query is an array that looks like
[image]

Is this possible to do all in one go with one query?

Comment: I would be tempted to handle the json encoding in some kind of application code

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for getting date in one query:

```
select c.category,
JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('sub_category', cv.category, 'date', cv.createdAt)))
from category c,
     category_value cv
where c.category = cv.p_category
group by c.category
```